# how to update multiple update using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how to update multiple update in database  using checkbox  with php mysql

```
<form  action="enableprofile1.php" method="post">

//user id 
<input type="hidden" name="id1[]" id="id1[]" value="<?php echo $sn;  ?>"  />

//user id 

//enable checkbox
<input type="checkbox" name="enable[]" id="enable[]"  value="1"  <?php if($en=='1'){ echo 'checked';}  ?> />
//enable checkbox
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="fontBold">
</form>
```

CAN I KNOW WHEN I UNCHECKED CHECKBOX CAN I STORE VALUE LIKE 0

Comment: please show php code, what you have tried ?

Comment: Please explain your requirement fully

Comment: <?php
include_once("includes/config.php");
if($_POST["id1"])
{
$enable=$_POST["enable"];

 $id1=$_POST["id1"];
 $id5=count($_POST["id1"]);
 for($i=0;$i<=$id5;$i++)
{

$enableupdate=mysql_query("UPDATE ` talent_uploads`  SET enable='$enable[$i]' WHERE sno='$id1[$i]'  ");
 if($enableupdate)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert(\'Your Setting has been saved successfully\');
window.location = "EditProfilePictures.php";
</script>';
}

}
}
?>

Comment: @rock Add in question using code block, not comments

Comment: I WANT TO UPDATE MULTIPLE UPDATE WHEN THE USER CLICKS MULTIPLE CHECKBOX USING PHP MYSQL

Comment: @rock append your question to existing question

Comment: echo your update queries and check in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note:

- Made this code assuming you're using MySQLi Prepared Statement
- I explained the code in a comment form `/* */`
- I know that your HTML code is just a sample, but the value of your checkbox is set to only `1`. I hope that it's not. I also assume that the value of those checkboxes is coming from your database.
- Looks like you don't include your connection or don't know how to establish one, so I'll be updating my answer...right...now.
- I'm guessing that user has only two choices, 1 and 0, or enable and disable. So, again, I updated the code.
- Don't shout? (Just kiddin')

Your enableprofile1.php should look like this:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con = new mysqli("YourHost", "YourUsername", "YourPassword", "yourDataBaseName"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

if(isset($_POST["save"])){ /* IF SAVE BUTTON IS CLICKED */

  /* STORE THE PASSED DATA FROM YOUR FORM VIA POST */
  $enable = $_POST["enable"];
  $hiddenid = $_POST["id1"];
  $total = count($enable); /* COUNT TOTAL ARRAY */

  for($x=0;$x<=$total;$x++){ /* RUN A LOOP THAT CHECKS ALL DATA */

    if(!empty($enable[$x])){ $todo=1; } /* IF ENABLE IS CHECKED */
    else { $todo=0; } /* IF ENABLE IS NOT CHECKED */

     $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = ? WHERE yourID = ?"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY CONNECTION VARIABLE, TABLE NAME AND COLUMN NAME */
     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $todo, $hiddenid[$x]); /* BIND PASSED DATA TO THE QUERY */
     $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET SAVE */

?>
```

Add this to your form:

```
...
<?php
  $counter=0;

//user id 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id1[$counter]" id="id1[]" value="'.$sn.'"  />';

// user id

//enable checkbox
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="enable[$counter]" id="enable[]"  value="1" if($en=='1'){ echo 'checked';}  />';

$counter=$counter+1; /* INCREMENT $counter FOR EVERY LOOP */

?>
...
```

Comment: I WILL CHECK THIS WAIT

Comment: IT SAYING Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in  on line 14

Comment: I DON'T KNOW HOW TO UPDATE MULTIPLE UPDATE SO I KEPT 1

Comment: @rock - updated it. Please take note of the comments I've made and replace the necessary data with the establishment of connection and query.

Comment: IT'S WORKING CAN I KNOW WHEN I UNCHECKED CHECKBOX CAN I STORE VALUE LIKE 0

Comment: @rock - I updated again the answer. Just uncheck the checkbox and press the Save button.

Comment: thanks for help i was not able to update when multiple   unchecked for one  is working

Comment: @rock - try it again. Updated my answer

Comment: i tried but when i unchecked multiple it's not working please check once

Comment: IT'S NOT WOKING I TRIED TO DO BUT IT'S UPDATING ONLY ONE AT ONCE..Regards